# Is this 1.2" vinyl tube on the 1/2" ABS pipe the correct size?

Tags: plumbing, vinyl, fitting, pipe-fitting, abs

I have the [following 1-1/2" to 1/2" ABS wye](https://pexhouse.com/product/1-1-2-x-1-1-2-x-1-2-abs-dishwasher-y/). Initially I connected a 1/2" OD vinyl tubing but this was way too small and I was told the 1/2" here refers to ID. So I got an 1/2" ID 5/8" OD tube as shown below:

[image]

I was able to pull the tube on but it was very hard and I can't move it farther than on the picture.

I think that works but I am wondering if this is still not the right vinyl tubing.

The tube carries condensate from my heat pump + HPWH via a pump ("Little Giant Condensate Drain Pump").

Comment: Looks OK to me. What is this tube carrying?

Comment: Thanks, good to hear. Maybe write answer to accept? Tube is carrying condensate from HPWH and HP. I'll add this to the post.

Comment: There is some range of sizes that will work.  heating the tubing with boiling water or a heat gun can make fitment easier.  you probably need a trap after the wye,